# Leer valores de archivos

Tags: python, archivo

Hola este es el código en el estoy trabajando

```
import os
from random import randint
from random import uniform
num_sensor1 = randint(1,10)
valor1 = uniform(0,100)
num_sensor2 = randint(1,10)
valor2 = uniform(0,100)
archivo = open("Sensor.txt","w")
archivo.write("El numero del sensor de Temperatura es: " + str(num_sensor1) + "\n")
archivo.write("Y su valor es: " + str(valor1) + "\n\n")
archivo.write("El numero del sensor de Humedad es: " + str(num_sensor2) + "\n")
archivo.write("Y su valor es: " + str(valor2) + "\n\n")
archivo.close()
```

Mi duda es como puedo volver a obtener los valores leyendo el archivo

Comment: Vuelve a abrirlo en modo lectura ("r") y usa `archivo.read()` para leer el contenido completo, o `readlines()` para obtener una lista con las líneas. Luego tendrás que procesar esas cadenas para encontrar el dato en sí (con `split()` o con expresiones regulares)

Answer (score 1):

Hola para poder leer y escribir tu archivo debes modificar tu codigo por lo siguiente:

```
archivo = open("Sensor.txt","r+")
```

posteriormente puedes almacenar los datos con la siguiente declaracion:

```
datos = archivo.read()
```

Comment: y finalmente cerrar el archivo con `archivo.close()`

Comment: por cierto... como soluciona esto el problema??